# How to trigger AWS lambda function 5 times per second?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am implementing a solution that involves an S3 event triggers SQS and that triggers a Lambda function.

I want the lambda function to get triggered only 5 times per second even though there are 100 S3 events.
For this, i tried to use the "reserved concurrency" option set to 5 for the lambda function.
But. even then i see that it gets executed more than 5 times per second.

Can anyone let me know what could be the possible issue here ?

Comment: Set your reserved concurrency to 1, and make your function to run 15 seconds (add sleep in it) if you need.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the sleep part ? What is the use of that ? and give an example maybe. @Marcin

Comment: It depends on your programing language. For python, for example, it is `time.sleep()` method. It ensures that the function will run for no less then given time. So if you have concurrency of 1, and each function runs for 12 seconds, you can have exactly 5 function executions within 1 minute. You will obviously pay for this extra time, but this will achieve what you want to do.

Comment: In cloudwatch logs i see that the execution time for the lambda function is in milliseconds, appx 60ms. And i don't want to execute the lambda function more than 5 times per second. Will this work even in this scenario if i set the concurrency to 1 .?  @Marcin

Comment: Oh. I see you want 5 times per second, not minute. At this rate what does it matter if its 5 times or 10 times per second?

Comment: I am invoking a fargate task from this lambda function, and the service limit is that i cannot trigger more than 10 fargate tasks per second. So, i want to limit the lambda function invocations per second. @Marcin